# Struggling to get widgets working in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, matplotlib-widget

I don't know why but I am really struggling to get widgets working well in python. I try to look at examples about how to use them but I don't know how to extrapolate that to get it to work with my code. I am trying to get a figure to display widgets such that the type, frequency, phase, and other variables adjust the graph itself.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets as widgets
from scipy import signal
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons

A = 1
ang_f = 5
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 1000)
phase = 0

s0 = A*np.sin(ang_f*t + phase)
s2 = A*signal.sawtooth(ang_f*t + phase)
s1 = A*signal.square(ang_f*t + phase)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l, = ax.plot(t, s1, lw=2, color='red')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.4)


def sinf(x, omega):
    return np.sin(omega*x)


def sliderCallback(val):
    #  """ 'val' is the current value selected by the slider
    #    Recalculate sine values with val as the frequency """
    axesHandle.set_ydata(sinf(x, val))
    plt.draw()  # Redraw the axes


def clickcallback(val):
    #   'val' is the current value selected by the slider
    #    Recalculate sine values with val as the frequency
    axesHandle.set_ydata(sinf(x, val))
    plt.draw()  # Redraw the axes


def closeCallback(event):
    plt.close('all')  # Close all open figure windows


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))
ax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7])

axesHandle, = plt.plot(x, sinf(x, 1), lw=2, color='red')

# Add axis to contain the slider
fax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.04, 0.35, 0.03])    # Frequency
tax = plt.axes([0.1, 0.12, 0.35, 0.03])    # Time
sax_3 = plt.axes([0.60, 0.1, 0.35, 0.03])  # Number of points
pax = plt.axes([0.60, 0.05, 0.35, 0.03])    # Phase
rax = plt.axes([0.85, 0.65, 0.12, 0.15])    # Type
bax = plt.axes([0.85, 0.85, 0.1, 0.1])    # Close

pointshandle = widgets.Slider(sax_3, 'Number of points', 1, 200,
                              valfmt='%0.0f')
pointshandle.on_changed(sliderCallback)

graphchoice = widgets.RadioButtons(rax, ('Sine', 'Squarewave', 'Sawtooth'))
graphchoice.on_clicked(clickcallback)

freqhandle = widgets.Slider(fax, 'Frequancy (Hz)', 0, 5, valinit=1)
freqhandle.on_changed(sliderCallback)

phasehandle = widgets.Slider(pax, 'Phase', 0, 0*np.pi, valinit=0)
phasehandle.on_changed(sliderCallback)

timehandle = widgets.Slider(tax, 'Time (s)', 1, 10, valinit=1)
timehandle.on_changed(sliderCallback)

buttonHandle = widgets.Button(bax, 'Close')
buttonHandle.on_clicked(closeCallback)


def hzfunc(label):
    hzdict = {'Sine': s0, 'Squarewave': s1, 'Sawtooth': s2}
    ydata = hzdict[label]
    l.set_ydata(ydata)
    plt.draw()


graphchoice.on_clicked(hzfunc)
```

I'm really lost so any tips to put me on the right path would be much appreciated, im just so confused atm.

Comment: Please describe what specific problem you are having. It is not clear what your question is exactly.

Comment: Sorry if the question was confusing, that's my fault for having multiple parts. The main one would be plotting the graph where I use a RadioButton to change the graph from a sine to a sawtooth or square wave.